# NSPredicate nested or subquery?

Tags: ios, subquery, nspredicate

I am trying to write a NSPredicate that will return all ingredients of a given Recipe.  My entity Recipe has a recipeName, so I want to specify the recipeName, then the Recipe has a relationship to IngredientList which has a to-many relationship with Ingredients.  I want to grab all Ingredient.ingredientNames of a specified recipe.

Here is my data model.
[image: screenshot]

I have tried something like this but it won't compile, and I am sure there's something wrong with my for loop:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext];

// Construct a fetch request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipeName==%@", targetRecipe.recipeName];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
self.theRecipeArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSLog(@"The recipe you found was %@", [theRecipeArray objectAtIndex:0]);

//Query the one Recipe for all ingredients?
for (ingredient.IngredientName * Ingredient.ingredientName in theRecipeArray)
    [ingredientsArray addObject: ingredientName];
```

would give me the right recipe, but then how do I grab its ingredientList and all of its ingredients??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Recipe *recipe = [theRecipeArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

is the recipe that you found. The related ingredients are simply

```
NSArray *ingredients = [recipe.ingredientList.ingredient allObjects];
```

(`allObjects` is necessary only to get an `NSArray` instead of a `NSSet`.)
Then you get an array with all the names via Key-Value Coding:

```
NSArray *ingredientNames = [ingredients valueForKey:@"ingredientName"];
```